# How can i access the Progress bar with mouse cursor in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

i Am using Mb Progress Bar. in which the progress bar is sccessing automatically. here  i want to move the progress bar with my  mouse cursor.

i am using Github Library
https://github.com/matibot/MBCircularProgressBar

This library gives me animated progress bar which runs automatically on button click. i want exactly this one. but  it should not be automatically. i want to move it by my cursor  like hand moment.

this is my code:::

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MBCircularProgressBarView  *progressBar;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *animatedSwitch;

@end

@implementation MBViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// pan gesture detects circle dragging
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pv = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
//[self addGestureRecognizer:pv];
[self.progressBar addGestureRecognizer:pv];
}

- (IBAction)animate:(UIButton *)sender {
[UIView animateWithDuration:self.animatedSwitch.on * 1.f animations:^{
    self.progressBar.value = 100.f - self.progressBar.value;
}];
}
  # pragma mark detect pan and determine angle of pan location vs. center of circular revolution
 - (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pv {
   self.progressBar.value = 100.f - self.progressBar.value;
}
```

Anyone can have idea. please help me for this::

Comment: Why not plain UIProgressView and setting its progress using .progress property ??

Comment: so how can i set the  values when i will move with my cursor.

Comment: yourProgressViewWithProgress.progress = yourValue :) thats it buddy :)

Comment: moreover if you want to capture the progress using users swipe there is a inbuilt component called UISlider use it, you can customise the slider head, slider tint colour, and many other things :)

Comment: thanku for replying me @sandeep but i need circular progress bar which should be exact same with given lilnk demo. have u seen the git hub link